# No custom elements in polymer app

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I have a polymer app that runs fine i Dartium, but when I export to javascript it will not run. There are no error messages, but I get this warning:

> Target of URI does not exist: 'maindocument.html.0.dart'

It refers to this line:

```dart
<script type="application/dart" src="maindocument.html.0.dart"></script>
```

in a file called 'maindocument.html' created by the build.

This is the 'original' 'maindocument.html':

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="maindocument.css">

    <link rel="import" href="maincontroller.html">

    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="sample_container_id">
      <main-controller></main-controller>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is 'maincontroller.html':

```dart
<link rel="import" href="postedItem.html">

<polymer-element name="main-controller">
  <template>
    <style>
    </style>
    <div>
      <posted-item></posted-item>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="maincontroller.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

'maincontroller.dart' has no functionality yet.
Is it a problem with nested custom elements?

Comment: After building to JavaScript the entry page still contains the script tag that refers to the Dart script file but the Dart files are currently not copied to the build output directory. Just ignore the warning referring the dart file or remove the dart script tag manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `maincontroller.dart` does not have a definition for `MainController` with a `CustomTag` annotation, then you'll have problems.

Try defining a `MainController` class or add a `noscript` attribute to your `<polymer-element>` tag if you don't need any code for your element.

Comment: Actually after giving it a rest, and coming back to it after a few days, the problem was gone. Maybe a reboot was needed.

It had a definition for MainController (with custom tag), but it had no functionality.

Anyway, hopefully this post is useful for someone in the future. Thanks Justin.